# convert SOCK_DGRAM to SOCK_RAW

Tags: c

i want do the same thing to convert `SOCK_DGRAM` to SOCK_RAW in open source application.
 in `sendto` function it while socket is `SOCK_DGRAM` type then send only `RTP`data like this

here, `m->b_rptr` point out `RTP` header only. if i want to make SOCK_RAW then what buffer i have to pass in send to function. at  which point buffer point????

```
enter code here
error = sendto (sockfd, (char*)m->b_rptr, (int) (m->b_wptr - m->b_rptr), 0,destaddr,destlen);
```

Comment: Once you create a socket of a specific type, it will always be of that specific type, you can't change the type once it's created.

Comment: Also, I assume you mean the [Real-time Transport Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)? Which can be encapsulated in either TCP or UDP, meaning you don't need raw sockets at all.

Comment: Oh, and as a warning: Since RTP is an application-layer protocol, it needs a transport-layer protocol (like TCP or UDP) below it. If you use raw sockets, you have to handle the transport-layer yourself (i.e. you need to implement the complete UDP or TCP yourself in your code). So my advice to you is: Don't use raw sockets!

Comment: but while socket use SOCK_DGRAM the IP/UDP header are created by kernel. but i want to use IP/UDP/RTP header so i have to create RAW socket any other option available while socket type is SOCK_DGRAM nd without creating RAW socket i use IP/UDP/RTP header ??

Comment: If you have an UDP socket, and send the RTP header, you *have* the IP/UDP/RTP combination you want. You send the application-layer header (and data), the transport-layer *adds* the transport header, the IP-layer *adds* the IP header, the link-layer *adds* the MAC (ethernet) header and finally the physical layer converts all of that to electrical or light signals.

Comment: thank you. as you told each layer add header and data respectively.but i cant find out that at one point whole buffer that contain this IP/UDP/RTP packet.

Comment: You can use a packet-sniffer such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: wireshark detect all headers and also display its proper value but from code i cant find out packet buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new socket descriptor (First parameter you have passed to sendto in your post) with SOCK_RAW and no changes to memory pointer.